# Deployment of Entity Framework application using SQL server 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework, deployment

I made an wpf application on .Net Framework 4.0. It is using entity framework and SQL server 2012 as a database.

Now I want to deploy this machine on another computer. What needs to be installed on that machine. I am assuming that fresh OS has been installed on target machine.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio do you use?

Comment: Which edition? Express or Pro/Premium/Ultimate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've already deployed the same application with install shield, here's the list of all needed deps (downloadable for free from microsoft website) from **WinXP SP2 to Win8** and works on both x84 | x64

**The no need for entity Framework its already in .netFX 4.0**

you can also specify the sqlserver configuration parameters using

`SQLEXPR_x86_ENU /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQLENGINE /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL Service" /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /TCPENABLED=1  /NPENABLED=1 /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you plan to deploy really. Generally, you'll need a copy of SQL Server (full or express edition depending on budget / whether the limitations of express are a problem for your situation).

You will also need to install the .NET framework and any other dependencies (depending of your app). You could use Visual Studio to create an installer, then it will bundle all of the dependencies and make the installation on other machines nice and easy.

Comment: I used the publish wizard on my visual studio project. It has given me one exe and 2 3 more files. I tried to run them on another machine. But application crashed.

Comment: Have you installed the .NET framework on the other machine? Does it give an error message when it crashes?

Comment: .NET framework is installed. Application actually opens but it crashes when it tries to connect with database. I want to ask that do i need to install SQL server on client machine?

Comment: Yes you should install SQL Server on the client machine and host the database locally. It is possible to connect to SQL Server that is running on another machine (using named pipes etc), but this will be much slower and more complex than running it on the same machine so local is probably preferable.